# Proving inverse direction of cancellation laws on natural numbers

Tags: natural-numbers

I already proved the following using proof by induction: For all $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$ we have:
\begin{align*}
a+c=b+c \Rightarrow a=b
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
a\cdot c = b\cdot c \Rightarrow a=b .
\end{align*}

Now I want to show that for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$ have that
\begin{align*}
a=b\Rightarrow a+c=b+c
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
a=b\Rightarrow a\cdot c= b\cdot c,
\end{align*}
but cannot come up with a proper way to do so. Anyone got an idea?

Also got a question about terminology. I know the statements I've already proved are called cancellation law of addition and cancellation law of multiplication, respectively. Is there also a name for the implications $a=b\Rightarrow a*c=b*c$ and the equivalence $a=b\Leftrightarrow a*c=b*c$?

Comment: I think induction on $c$ may work.

Comment: Thanks, guess you just reminded me about the negative effects of sleep deprivation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us prove by induction on $c$. The proposition clearly holds for $c = 0$:
\begin{align*}
a = b \Rightarrow 0 + a = 0 + b
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Now suppose it holds for $c$ and we want to prove it holds for $s(c)$, where $s$ is the successor function.

Moroever, according to its definition as well as the commutative property, one has that
\begin{align*}
a + c = b + c & \Rightarrow s(a + c) = s(b + c)\\\\
& \Rightarrow s(c + a) = s(c + b)\\\\
& \Rightarrow s(c) + a = s(c) + b\\\\
& \Rightarrow a + s(c) = b + s(c)
\end{align*}

Similarly, we can handle the proof for the multiplication.

Let $c = 0$. Then we have that
\begin{align*}
a = b \Rightarrow 0\cdot a = 0 = 0\cdot b
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Now suppose that the proposed relation holds for $c$ and we shall prove it holds for $s(c)$ as well.

Since $a = b$, according to the definition of multiplication and its commutative property, it results that

\begin{align*}
a\cdot c = b\cdot c & \Rightarrow a\cdot c + a = b\cdot c + b\\\\
& \Rightarrow c\cdot a + a = c\cdot b + b\\\\
& \Rightarrow s(c)\cdot a = s(c)\cdot b\\\\
& \Rightarrow a\cdot s(c) = b\cdot s(c)
\end{align*}
and we are done.

In order to answer this question, I assumed the definitions of addition and multiplication as given in the book "Analysis I" from Terence Tao as well as the corresponding commutative properties.

Hopefully this helps!